# Is Visitor Pattern valid in this scenario?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, visitor-pattern

The goal of my task is to design a small system which can run scheduled recurring tasks. A recurring task is something like "send an email to administrator every hour from 8:00 am to 5:00 pm, Monday through Friday".

I have a base class called *RecurringTask*.

```
public abstract class RecurringTask{

    // I've already figured out this part
    public bool isOccuring(DateTime dateTime){
        // implementation
    }

    // run the task
    public abstract void Run(){

    }
}
```

And I have several classes which are inherited from *RecurringTask*. One of them is called *SendEmailTask*.

```
public class SendEmailTask : RecurringTask{
    private Email email;

    public SendEmailTask(Email email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public override void Run(){
        // need to send out email
    }
}
```

And I have a *EmailService* which can helps me to send out an email.

The last class is *RecurringTaskScheduler*, it's responsible for loading tasks from cache or database and run the task.

```
public class RecurringTaskScheduler{

    public void RunTasks(){
        // Every minute, load all tasks from cache or database
        foreach(RecuringTask task : tasks){
            if(task.isOccuring(Datetime.UtcNow)){
                task.run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my problem: where should I put *EmailService*?

**Option1**: Inject *EmailService* into *SendEmailTask*

```
public class SendEmailTask : RecurringTask{
    private Email email;

    public EmailService EmailService{ get; set;}

    public SendEmailTask (Email email, EmailService emailService){
        this.email = email;
        this.EmailService = emailService;
    }

    public override void Run(){
        this.EmailService.send(this.email);
    }
}
```

There are already some discussions on whether we should inject a service into an entity, and most people agree it's not a good practice. See [this article](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/03/04/How-not-to-inject-services-in-entities).

**Option2:** If...Else in *RecurringTaskScheduler*

```
public class RecurringTaskScheduler{
    public EmailService EmailService{get;set;}

    public class RecurringTaskScheduler(EmailService emailService){
        this.EmailService = emailService;
    }

    public void RunTasks(){
        // load all tasks from cache or database
        foreach(RecuringTask task : tasks){
            if(task.isOccuring(Datetime.UtcNow)){
                if(task is SendEmailTask){
                    EmailService.send(task.email); // also need to make email public in SendEmailTask
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been told If...Else and cast like above is not OO, and will bring more problems.

**Option3:** Change the signature of *Run* and create *ServiceBundle*.

```
public class ServiceBundle{
    public EmailService EmailService{get;set}
    public CleanDiskService CleanDiskService{get;set;}
    // and other services for other recurring tasks

}
```

Inject this class into *RecurringTaskScheduler*

```
public class RecurringTaskScheduler{
    public ServiceBundle ServiceBundle{get;set;}

    public class RecurringTaskScheduler(ServiceBundle serviceBundle){
        this.ServiceBundle = ServiceBundle;
    }

    public void RunTasks(){
        // load all tasks from cache or database
        foreach(RecuringTask task : tasks){
            if(task.isOccuring(Datetime.UtcNow)){
                task.run(serviceBundle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The *Run* method of *SendEmailTask* would be

```
public void Run(ServiceBundle serviceBundle){
    serviceBundle.EmailService.send(this.email);
}
```

I don't see any big problems with this approach.

**Option4**: Visitor pattern.
The basic idea is create a visitor which will encapsulate services just like *ServiceBundle*.

```
public class RunTaskVisitor : RecurringTaskVisitor{
    public EmailService EmailService{get;set;}
    public CleanDiskService CleanDiskService{get;set;}

    public void Visit(SendEmailTask task){
        EmailService.send(task.email);
    }

    public void Visit(ClearDiskTask task){
        //
    }
}
```

And we also need to change the signature of *Run* method. The *Run* method of *SendEmailTask* is

```
public void Run(RecurringTaskVisitor visitor){
    visitor.visit(this);
}
```

It is a typical implementation of Visitor Pattern, and the visitor will be injected into *RecurringTaskScheduler*.

In summary:
Among these four approaches, which one is the best for my scenario? And are there any big difference between Option3 and Option4 for this problem?

Or do you have better idea on this problem? Thanks!

**Update 5/22/2015**: I think Andy's answer summarizes my intention really well; if you are still confused about the problem itself, I suggest reading his post first.

I just found out my problem is very similar to *Message Dispatch* problem, which leads to Option5.

**Option5**: Convert my problem to *Message Dispatch*.
There is a one-to-one mapping between my problem and *Message Dispatch* problem:

*Message Dispatcher* : Receive *IMessage* and dispatch sub classes of *IMessage* to their corresponding handlers. → RecurringTaskScheduler

*IMessage* : An interface or an abstract class. → RecurringTask

*MessageA* : Extends from *IMessage*, having some additional information. → SendEmailTask

*MessageB* : Another subclass of *IMessage*. → CleanDiskTask

*MessageAHandler* : When receive *MessageA*, handle it → SendEmailTaskHandler, which contains EmailService, and will send out an email when it receives SendEmailTask

*MessageBHandler* : Same as *MessageAHandler*, but handle *MessageB* instead. → CleanDiskTaskHandler

The hardest part is how to dispatch different kind of *IMessage* to different handlers. Here is a useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477471/design-pattern-for-handling-multiple-message-types).

I really like this approach, it doesn't pollute my entity with service, and it doesn't have any *God* class.

Comment: You have not tagged a language or platform, but I recommend looking into [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Your platform may have a library that works similarly (e.g. [jcron](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/jcron_scheduler/) which seems sort of defunct). Scheduling jobs and tasks is largely a solved problem: have you looked into other options before rolling your own? Were there reasons for not using them?

Comment: @Snowman We may switch to a mature library later. It all depends on my manager. The reason I post this question is I want to find a way to solve this 'kind' of problem. I've seen this kind of problem more than once, and couldn't find out an elegant solution. So i am wondering whether i did something wrong.

Comment: Fair enough, I always try to recommend code reuse if possible though.

Comment: `SendEmailTask` seems more like a service than an entity to me. I would go for option 1 without and hesitation.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Could you explain why SendEmailTask is a service not an entity? Task Information will be stored into database, like email content, taskId, its recurrence pattern.

Comment: @Sher10ck: No, I can't really explain, which is also why I wrote it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The GoF Visitor pattern says it "lets you define a new operation without changing the classes of the elements on which it operates." I think `RecurringTask` is the kind of operation you'd want to add easily, but I fail to see what are the "classes of the elements on which it operates." The only problem you clearly state is "where should I put EmailService?" and that's not a pattern-type problem.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I add some code to demonstrate how to adopt Visitor Pattern in my case.I have to admit i don't see any advantage using Visitor Pattern here, I personally prefer Option3. I am also curious how others solve this 'kind' of problem.

Comment: What's missing (to me) for Visitor is the class structure that `accept`s visitors. The motivation for Visitor is that you have many class types in some aggregate that need visiting, and it's not convenient to modify their code for each new functionality (operation). I still don't see what those aggregate objects are, and think that Visitor is not appropriate. If it's the case, you should edit your question (which refers to visitor).

Comment: The aggregate objects are the sub classes of *RecurringTask*, like *SendEmailTask*, *CleanDiskTask*, etc, it could be a lot of this kind of tasks. Could you give me some reasons why i shouldn't adopt Visitor Pattern here? One reason maybe the code is not easy to understand at first glance , that's why i prefer Option3.

Comment: I don't see what option 3 helps. It looks like option 1 except now your services are injected in a bundle rather than on their own, and into `run` rather than the constructor. Neither of those seem to add any meaningful abstraction or protection.

Comment: @BenAaronson The *ServiceBundle* itself is a service, so i can use some IOC to set it up (Inject service into another service shouldn't be a problem). But *RecurringTask* and its sub classes are entity, I can't use IOC to set them up. Or, even i could, it's not considered to be a good practice. I think it's the major difference btw Option1 and Option3.

Comment: Option 4 just looks like a more confusing version of option 3 to me.  I'm not sure either one is the best, but I'd prefer 3 over 4.

Answer (score 4):

I would say **Option 1** is the best route to take. The reason you should not dismiss it is that the `SendEmailTask` is **not** an entity. An entity is an object concerned with holding data and state. Your class has very little of that. In fact, it is not an entity, but it *holds* an entity: the `Email` object you are storing. That means that `Email` should not take a service, or have a `#Send` method. Instead, you should have services that take entities, such as your `EmailService`. So you are already following the idea of keeping services out of entities.

Since `SendEmailTask` is not an entity, it is therefore perfectly fine to inject the email and the service into it, and that should be done through the constructor. By doing constructor injection, we can be sure that `SendEmailTask` is always ready to perform it's job.

Now let's look at **why not** to do the other options (specifically with respect to [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)).

#### Option 2

You've been rightly told that branching on type like that will bring more headaches down the road. Let's look at why. First, `if`s tend to cluster and grow. Today, it's a task to send emails, tomorrow, every different type of class needs a different service or other behavior. Managing that `if` statement becomes a nightmare. Since we are branching on type (and in this case *explicit type*), we are subverting the type system built into our language.

Option 2 is not Single Responsibility (SRP) because the formerly reusable `RecurringTaskScheduler` now has to know about all these different types of tasks, and about all the different kinds of services and behaviors they might need. That class is much harder to reuse. It is also not Open/Closed (OCP). Because it needs to know about this kind of task or that one (or this kind of service or that one), disparate changes to tasks or services could force changes here. Add a new task? Add a new service? Change the way email is handled? Change `RecurringTaskScheduler`. Because the type of task matters, it does not adhere to Liskov Substitution (LSP). It can't just get a task and be done. It has to ask for the type and based on the type do this or do that. Rather than encapsulating the differences into the tasks, we are pulling all of that into the `RecurringTaskScheduler`.

#### Option 3

Option 3 has some big problems. Even in [the article you link to](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/03/04/How-not-to-inject-services-in-entities), the author discourages doing this:

> - You can still use a static service locator…
> - I avoid service locator when I can, especially when the service locator must be static…

You are creating a [service locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) with your `ServiceBundle` class. In this case, it doesn't appear to be static, but it still has many of the problems inherent in a service locator. Your dependencies are now hidden away under this `ServiceBundle`. If I give you the following API of my cool new task:

```
class MyCoolNewTask implements RecurringTask
{
    public bool isOccuring(DateTime dateTime) {
        return true; // It's always happenin' here!
    }

    public void Run(ServiceBundle bundle) {
        // yeah, some awesome stuff here
    }
}
```

What are the services I am using? What services need to be mocked out in a test? What's to stop me from using *every* service in the system, just because?

If I want to use your task system to run some tasks, I now am dependent on every service in your system, even if I only use a few or even none at all.

The `ServiceBundle` is not really SRP because it needs to know about *every* service in your system. It is also not OCP. Adding new services means changes to the `ServiceBundle`, and changes to the `ServiceBundle` may mean disparate changes to tasks elsewhere. `ServiceBundle` does not Segregate its Interface (ISP). It has a sprawling interface of all these services, and because it's just a provider for those services, we could consider its interface to encompass the interfaces of all of the services it provides as well. Tasks no longer adhere to Dependency Inversion (DIP), because their dependencies are obfuscated behind the `ServiceBundle`. This also does not adhere to the [Principle of Least Knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (aka the Law of Demeter) because things know about many more things than they have to.

#### Option 4

Previously, you had lots of small objects that were able to operate independently. Option 4 takes all of these objects and smashes them together into a single `Visitor` object. This object acts as a [god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) over all of your tasks. It reduces your `RecurringTask` objects to anemic shadows that simply call out to a visitor. All of the behavior moves to the `Visitor`. Need to change behavior? Need to add a new task? Change `Visitor`.

The more challenging part is that, because all of the different behaviors are all in a single class, changing some *polymorphicly* drags along all of the other behavior. For example, we want to have two different ways to send email (they should use different servers maybe?). How would we do it? We could create an `IVisitor` interface and implement that, potentially duplicating code, like `#Visit(ClearDiskTask)` from our original visitor. Then if we come up with a new way to clear a disk, we have to implement and duplicate again. Then we want both kinds of changes. Implement and duplicate again. These two different, disparate behaviors are inextricably linked.

Maybe instead we could just subclass `Visitor`? Subclass with new email behavior, subclass with new disk behavior. No duplication so far! Subclass with both? Now one or the other needs to be duplicated (or both if that's your preference).

Let's compare to option 1: We need a new email behavior. We can create a new `RecurringTask` that does the new behavior, inject in its dependencies, and add it to the collection of tasks in the `RecurringTaskScheduler`. We don't even need to talk about clearing disks, because that responsibility is somewhere else entirely. We also still have the full array of OO tools at our disposal. We could decorate that task with logging, for example.

Option 1 will give you the least pain, and is the most correct way to handle this situation.

Comment: Your analysis on Otion2,3,4 is fantastic! It really helps me a lot. But for Option1, i would argue that *SendEmailTask * is an entity. It has id, it has its recurring pattern, and other useful information which should be stored in db. I think Andy summarize my intention well. Maybe a name like *EMailTaskDefinitions * is more appropriate. i don't want to pollute my entity with my service code. Euphoric mentions some problem if i inject a service into entity. I also update my question and include Option5, which i think is the best solution so far.

Comment: @Sher10ck If you are pulling configuration for your `SendEmailTask` out of a database, then that configuration should be a separate configuration class that should also be injected into your `SendEmailTask`. If you are generating data from your `SendEmailTask`, you should create a memento object to store state and put that into your database.

Comment: I need to pull the configuration from db, so are u suggesting injecting both `EMailTaskDefinitions` and `EmailService` into `SendEmailTask`? Then in the `RecurringTaskScheduler`, I need inject something like `SendEmailTaskRepository` whose responsibility is loading definition and service and inject them into `SendEmailTask`. But I would argue now the `RecurringTaskScheduler` needs to know Repository of every task, like `CleanDiskTaskRepository`. And i need to change `RecurringTaskScheduler` each time I have a new task(to add repository into the Scheduler).

Comment: @Sher10ck The `RecurringTaskScheduler` should only be aware of the concept of a generalized task repository and a `RecurringTask`. By doing this, it can depend upon abstractions. The task repositories can be injected into the constructor of `RecurringTaskScheduler`. Then the different repositories need only be known where `RecurringTaskScheduler` is instantiated (or could be hidden away in a factory and called from there). Because it only depends on the abstractions, `RecurringTaskScheduler` does not need to change with each new task. That is the essence of dependency inversion.

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at existing libraries e.g. spring quartz or spring batch (I'm not sure what fits your needs most)?

## To your question:

I assume the problem is, that you want to persist some metadata to the task in a polymorphic way, so an e-mail task has e-mail addresses assigned, a log-task a log-level, and so on.
You can store a list of those in memory or in your database but to seperate concerns you don't want to have the entity polluted with service-code.

#### My proposed solution:

I would separate the running- and the data-part of the task, to have e.g. `TaskDefinition` and a `TaskRunner`. The TaskDefinition has a reference to a TaskRunner or a factory that creates one (e.g. if some setup is required like the smtp-host). The factory is a specific one - it only can handle `EMailTaskDefinition`s and returns only instances of `EMailTaskRunner`s. This way it is more OO and change safe - if you introduce a new task-type you have to introduce a new specific factory (or reuse one), if you don't you can't compile.

This way you would end up with a dependency: entity layer --> service layer and back again, because the Runner needs information stored in the entity and probably wants to make an update to its state in the DB.

You could break the circle by using a generic factory, which takes *a* TaskDefinition and returns a *specific* TaskRunner, but that would require lots of ifs. You *could* use reflection to find a runner that is similarly named as your definition, but be cautious this approach can cost some performance, and may lead to runtime errors.

P.S. I'm assuming Java here. I think it's similar in .net. The main problem here is the double binding.

## To the visitor pattern

I think it was rather intended to be used to exchange an algorithm for different kinds of data objects at runtime, than for pure double binding purposes. For example if you have different kinds of insurances and different kinds of calculating them, e.g. because different countries require it. Then you choose a specific calculation method and apply it on several insurances.

In your case you would choose a specific task-strategy (e.g. email) and apply it to all of your tasks, which is wrong because not all of them are email tasks.

P.S. I didn't test it, but I think your Option 4 won't work either, because it is double-binding again.

Comment: You summarize my intention really well, thx! I'd like to break the circle. Because letting *TaskDefiniton* holds an reference to *TaskRunner* or *factory* has same problem as Option1. I treat *factory* or *TaskRunner* as service. If *TaskDefinition* needs holds an reference to them, you have either inject the service into *TaskDefinition*, or use some static method, which is i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I completely disagree with that article. Services (concretely their "API") are important party of the Business Domain and as such will exist within Domain Model. And there is no problem with entities in business domain referencing something else in same business domain.

> When X send mail to Y.

Is a business rule. And to do that, service that sends mail is needed. And entity that handles `When X` should know about this service.

But there are some problems with implementation. It should be transparent to user of the entity, that the entity is using a service. So adding the service in constructor is not a good thing. This is also an issue, when you are deserializing the entity from database, because you need to set both the data of the entity and instances of services. Best solution I can think of is to use property injection after the entity was created. Maybe forcing each newly created instance of any entity to go through "initialize" method that injects all entities the entity needs.

Comment: What _article_ are you referring with that you disagree? However, interesting point of view on the domain model. Probably you can see it like that, though, people usually avoid mixing services into entities, because it will create a tight coupling very soon.

Comment: @Andy The one Sher10ck referenced in his question. And I don't see how it would create a tight coupling. Any badly written code can introduce tight coupling.

Answer (score 1):

That is a great question and an interesting problem. I propose that you use a combination of [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) and [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) patterns (pattern examples [here](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns)).

First lets define the task hierarchy. Notice that there are now multiple `run` methods to implement the Double Dispatch.

```
public abstract class RecurringTask {

    public abstract boolean isOccuring(Date date);

    public boolean run(EmailService emailService) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean run(ExecuteService executeService) {
        return false;
    }
}

public class SendEmailTask extends RecurringTask {

    private String email;

    public SendEmailTask(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOccuring(Date date) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run(EmailService emailService) {
        emailService.runTask(this);
        return true;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}

public class ExecuteTask extends RecurringTask {

    private String program;

    public ExecuteTask(String program) {
        this.program = program;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOccuring(Date date) {
        return true;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return program;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run(ExecuteService executeService) {
        executeService.runTask(this);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next lets define the `Service` hierarchy. We will use `Service`s to form the Chain of Responsibility.

```
public abstract class Service {

    private Service next;

    public Service(Service next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void handleRecurringTask(RecurringTask req) {
        if (next != null) {
            next.handleRecurringTask(req);
        }
    }
}

public class ExecuteService extends Service {

    public ExecuteService(Service next) {
        super(next);
    }

    void runTask(ExecuteTask task) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s running %s with content '%s'", this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                task.getClass().getSimpleName(), task.getName()));
    }

    public void handleRecurringTask(RecurringTask req) {
        if (!req.run(this)) {
            super.handleRecurringTask(req);
        }
    }
}

public class EmailService extends Service {

    public EmailService(Service next) {
        super(next);
    }

    public void runTask(SendEmailTask task) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s running %s with content '%s'", this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                task.getClass().getSimpleName(), task.getEmail()));
    }

    public void handleRecurringTask(RecurringTask req) {
        if (!req.run(this)) {
            super.handleRecurringTask(req);
        }
    }
}
```

The final piece is the `RecurringTaskScheduler` which orchestrates the loading and running process.

```
public class RecurringTaskScheduler{

    private List<RecurringTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    private Service chain;

    public RecurringTaskScheduler() {
        chain = new EmailService(new ExecuteService(null));
    }

    public void loadTasks() {
        tasks.add(new SendEmailTask("here comes the first email"));
        tasks.add(new SendEmailTask("here is the second email"));
        tasks.add(new ExecuteTask("/root/python"));
        tasks.add(new ExecuteTask("/bin/cat"));
        tasks.add(new SendEmailTask("here is the third email"));
        tasks.add(new ExecuteTask("/bin/grep"));
    }

    public void runTasks(){
        for (RecurringTask task : tasks) {
            if (task.isOccuring(new Date())) {
                chain.handleRecurringTask(task);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here is the example application demonstrating the system.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RecurringTaskScheduler scheduler = new RecurringTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.loadTasks();
        scheduler.runTasks();
    }
}
```

Running the application outputs:

EmailService running SendEmailTask with content 'here comes the first email'
EmailService running SendEmailTask with content 'here is the second email'
ExecuteService running ExecuteTask with content '/root/python'
ExecuteService running ExecuteTask with content '/bin/cat'
EmailService running SendEmailTask with content 'here is the third email'
ExecuteService running ExecuteTask with content '/bin/grep'

Comment: I may have a lot of *Task*. Every time I add a new *Task*, I need to change *RecurringTask* and I also need to change all its sub classes, because I need to add a new function like  *public abstract boolean run(OtherService otherService)*. I think Option4, the visitor pattern which also implement double dispatch has the same problem.

Comment: Good point. I edited my answer so that run(service) methods are defined in the RecurringTask and return false by default. This way, when you need to add another task class you don't need to touch the sibling tasks.